# Caching variables for events without making them global

Tags: javascript, jquery, variables, scope, jquery-events

You can say that this would apply to most events but in my case the `change` event for select boxes. I have two select boxes. I want to insert/re-insert depending the options from the select box depending on which option is selected within the first select box. I've managed to do this but with the caveat of making a global variable for the options I want to manipulate. Is there a way to do this within the event or some sort've workaround where the variable isn't global?

**HTML**

```
<select id="vehicles">
  <option value="motorcycle">Motorcycle</option>
  <option value="bicycle">Bicycle</option>
  <option value="unicycle">Unicycle</option>
</select>
<select id="speeds">
  <option class="remove" value="four">Four Speed</option>
  <option class="remove" value="three">Three Speed</option>
  <option class="remove" value="two">Two Speed</option>
  <option value="one">One Speed</option>
</select>
```

**JS**

```
$(function() {
  var options =  $(".remove");

  $("#vehicles").on("change", function() {
    if ($("option:selected").attr("value") == "unicycle") {
      options.detach();
    } else {
      $("#speeds").append(options)
    }
  });
});
```

**[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cc03xcx5/2/)**

Comment: What is expected result ?

Comment: The result remains the same I just want to remove the `options` variable from the global scope.

Comment: `js` at OP appear to detach , append to same parent element ? Not certain about expected results ?

Comment: Select the option "unicycle" and you'll see that 3/4 options are removed. If another option is selected they're re-inserted. Best seen in the fiddle.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/cc03xcx5/3/ ?

Comment: See post, utilizing http://api.jquery.com/data , http://api.jquery.com/clone

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
$(function() {        
    $("#vehicles")
    .data("clone", $(".remove").clone()) // `.remove` clone
    .on("change", function(e) {
        if ($(e.target).val() === "unicycle") {
            $("option[class=" + $(this).data("clone")[0].className + "]")
            .detach();
        } else {
            // append `.remove` `clone`,
            // if `#speeds` does not contain `.remove` `class`,
            // to prevent duplicate `.remove` collections being appended
            if (!$("#speeds *").hasClass("remove")) {
              $("#speeds").append($(this).data("clone"))
            }
        }
    });
});
```

jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/cc03xcx5/7/

Comment: Thanks! Can you explain how `data` is used in this particular instance?

Comment: @CarlEdwards `$("#vehicles").data("clone")` http://api.jquery.com/data stores a clone http://api.jquery.com/clone of `$(".remove")` elements . If the `remove` `class` is _not_ present within `#speeds`; e.g., after being detached, the `remove` clone at `.data("clone")` is appended to `#speeds` .

Comment: Ah I see. I wasn't aware until now that `clone` inside the `data` method served as a reference. Thanks for the insightful solution.

Comment: @CarlEdwards Can name the `.data()` any string; for example, `.data("abc", "value")` , does not have to be `.data("clone")`; still references the `value` set .  You are welcome:)

Comment: Yeah I just noticed that. Thanks for pointing that out as well.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you try something like:

```
$(function() {
    $("#vehicles").on("change", function() {
        if ($("option:selected").attr("value") == "unicycle") {
            $("#speeds option.remove").hide();
        } else {
            $("#speeds option").show();
        }
    });
});
```

I am not sure if that s what you want.

Comment: Using show/hide will remove the options but the select box still displays the first (and removed) option. Only when you click into it you see.

Comment: It s a bit farfetched but you can add the following line to select the first visible line: `$('#speeds').val( $('#speeds option:visible:first').val() );` I am sure there might be an easier solution